# Split a big ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, split, html-lists

I have a big ul list. With a lot of li items. I want split this big list in parts of 10. I make a script, but the script is not working. What do i wrong:

```
var maxItems = 10;
    var ul = $('.list-thumbnails');
    var current;
    ul.find('li').each(function(i, el) {
      if (i < maxItems) {
        // leave first 10 in the original list
        return;
      }
      if (i % maxItems == 0) {
        current =
            $(el)
                .closest('ul')
                .clone()
                .after($(el).closest('ul'));
      }
    .append(current);
});
```

Comment: Why do you try to work on the result list rather than try to change the creation of the list?

Comment: This is the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4tpnS/2/ I want split this big ul list. In parts of 10

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?? You are getting the text splitted by 10 chars w.r.t. jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code block as below. Please check it

Since your looping the $.each though you use append method it won't get reflected in the ul and so we need to remove the element.

```
var maxItems = 10;
            var ul = $('.list-thumbnails');
            var currentul;
            var elements = ul.find('li');
            elements.each(function (i, el) {
                if (i < maxItems) {
                    // leave first 10 in the original list
                    return;
                }
                if (i % maxItems == 0) {
                    currentul = $("<ul></ul>").addClass("new");
                    $(el).closest('ul').parent().append((currentul.append(el)));
                }
                else {
                    currentul.append(el)
                }

            });
            $('.list-thumbnails').find("li:gt(9)").remove();
```

Please check the below jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/aQ5K8/13/

Thanks 
Sridhar